# How to check if null is in stream?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Stream<Integer>` and want to know if there is a `null` in this stream. How do I check that? Using `.anyMatch(null)` throws me a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`anyMatch` accepts a *predicate*.

```
stream.anyMatch(x -> x == null)
```

or

```
stream.anyMatch(Objects::isNull)
```

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: I guess, you had a mindset like [`Predicate.isEqual(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-)…

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, using [my StreamEx library](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) you can write [`stream.has(null)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#has-T-)